# "End of file was encountered" appears after loading an image from the CameraRoll

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, arrays

I'm loading an image from the CameraRoll with the code below. I get this
error after the the `readMediaData()` function starts: `Error #2030: End of file was encountered at flash.utils::ByteArray/readUnsignedByte()`

I'm using Adobe Air 15 and an iPhone 6.
The EXIF package is from here: https://github.com/bashi/exif-as3
How to fix the error? This is my code:

```
import jp.shichiseki.exif.*;

var exif;
var mediaPromise:MediaPromise;
var dataSource:IDataInput;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var deviceCameraRoll:CameraRoll;

function loadImageFromCameraRoll(e:Event=null):void
{
    trace("loadImageFromCameraRoll");
    deviceCameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
    deviceCameraRoll.addEventListener(MediaEvent.SELECT, onSelected);
    deviceCameraRoll.browseForImage();
}

function onSelected(e:MediaEvent)
{
    trace("onSelected");
    mediaPromise = e.data;
    dataSource = mediaPromise.open();

    if (mediaPromise.isAsync)
    {
        trace( "Asynchronous media promise." );
        var eventSource:IEventDispatcher = dataSource as IEventDispatcher;
        eventSource.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onMediaLoaded );
    }
    else
    {
        trace( "Synchronous media promise." );
    }
}

function onMediaLoaded( event:Event ):void
{
    trace("Media load complete");
    readMediaData();
}



function readMediaData():void
{
    trace("readMediaData");
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded );
    loader.loadFilePromise(mediaPromise);

    var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    dataSource.readBytes(data);
    exif = new ExifInfo(data);

    trace("ORIENTATION: "+ getOrientation(exif.ifds.primary));
}

function imageLoaded( event:Event ):void
{
    trace("Image loaded asynchronously.");
    holder.addChild(loader );
}

function getOrientation(ifd:IFD):String
{
    var str:String = "";
    for (var entry:String in ifd)
    {
        if (entry == "Orientation")
        {
            str = ifd[entry];
        }
    }
    switch (str)
    {
        case "1" ://normal
            str = "NORMAL";
            break;
        case "3" ://rotated 180 degrees (upside down)
            str = "UPSIDE_DOWN";
            break;
        case "6" ://rotated 90 degrees CW
            str = "ROTATED_LEFT";
            break;
        case "8" ://rotated 90 degrees CCW
            str = "ROTATED_RIGHT";
            break;
        case "9" ://unknown
            str = "UNKNOWN";
            break;
    }
    return str;
}

btnload.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadImageFromCameraRoll);
```

Comment: What do you see if you add `trace("readMediaData " + dataSource.bytesAvailable);` to your `readMediaData` function?

Comment: @Brian It's 0. What does that mean? It says 0 but I can get the correct EXIF value from the loaded image with this line: `trace("ORIENTATION: "+ getOrientation(exif.ifds.primary));` Any ideas how to fix the error?

Comment: It means you can't actually read any data from your `dataSource`.  How are you getting the exif data?  The `trace()` in `readMediaData` should never be executed.

Comment: I'm getting the EXIF data through this line in the *readMediaData()* function: `trace("ORIENTATION: "+ getOrientation(exif.ifds.primary));` The output is correct but than the “End of file was encountered" error comes up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The EXIF reader below works for me: 
https://github.com/mikatalk/AS3-goodies/blob/master/utils/ExifReader.as
and
https://github.com/mikatalk/AS3-goodies/blob/master/utils/ImageOrientation.as